# Display a variable in Android Widget

Tags: java, android

I have a String variable that is declared and edited in the Main Activity.

I would like it to be display in a widget, but not sure how.

In the Widget file I have:

```
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetAmount, String.valueOf(number))
```

but the number variable is declared in another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send a `Broadcast` using an `Intent`, that contains the value you want to display in your App Widget. Create an `Intent` and add the value:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourAppWidgetProvider.class);
intent.putExtra("extra_value", value);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Now in your `AppWidgetProvider` class's onReceive you can access this value:

```
String value = intent.getStringExtra("extra_value");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So far I have

`public void updateWidget(int value) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppWidget.class);
     intent.putExtra("value", value);
     sendBroadcast(intent);
    }`

in my main and `String value = intent.getStringExtra("extra_value");`
in the appWidget class. However, the intent is not recognised in the AppWidget. Is there anything obvious I am missing? It just comes up intent cannot be resolved in eclipse.

Comment: @user1235720, Does AppWidget extend AppWidgetProvider? Does it's onReceive method get called after you send the broadcast?

Comment: Thanks Egor for the help. At this stage, I am very close. The AppWidget class is receiving the correct value, I just can't update the widget to display it. In appWidget I have `int value = intent.getIntExtra("Value", 0);
   RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
   remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetAmount, String.valueOf(value));`

Comment: @user1235720, OK then, so just manually call onUpdate from the onReceive, passing the right parameters. This should do it.

Comment: I have tried that for the last 2 hours but can't get it to work. `public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {` I have context but I don't know how to send an appWidgetManager or int[]

Comment: @user1235720, Here's a nice post on AppWidgets, I'm sure it will help you get things done: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html